# Can anyone help me understand one step in the proof of claim bounded Lebesgue integrable functions defined on a set of finite measure is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Here is the outline of the proof.
Take $\phi_n$ to be a sequence of increasing simple functions approaching f. 
Since $\phi_n$ is simple and measurable, f is measurable.

My question is where in the proof is it using the fact that f is defined on a finite measure?

Comment: Your hypothesis assert those functions are measurable? I guess you use "measurable" and "integrable" interchangebly.

Comment: Sorry. Was a typo. Corrected

Comment: Integrable functions are by definition measurable.

Comment: That is not an obvious fact to be. Maybe the book I'm using uses a different construction. I am reading royden's real analysis. This is theorem 7 on page 103.

Comment: Can you give the definition of an integrable function?

Comment: Assuming a function is nonnegative, it is integrable if the sup of the integral of bounded functions defined on a set of finite measure is less than infinity

Comment: How do you know that such a sequence $\phi_n$ exists in the first place?